# Firebase and LinkedIn Auth integration unknown route

Tags: firebase, http, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, linkedin-api

I've been examining [this code base](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/linkedin-auth) as an example of how to implement LinkedIn authorization to my project with a Firebase Backend. One thing I'm confused about is these lines:

```js
var code = getURLParameter("code");
var state = getURLParameter("state");
var error = getURLParameter("error");
if (error) {
  document.body.innerText = "Error back from the LinkedIn auth page: " + error;
} else if (!code) {
  // Start the auth flow.
  window.location.href = "/redirect";
}
```

at `window.location.href = '/redirect'`, I believe it is meant to invoke the cloud function called "redirect". In my code base, it simply goes to an unknown route and triggers my fallback. Am I wrong about the purpose of this line of code? Does anyone know any possible reasons it's not triggering the cloud function (console says 0 invocations)? What other information should I look into to try to debug this?

Comment: Do you have the firebase.json setup to point the `/redirect` path to the function?

Comment: @imjared I did not. Thanks so much for pointing that out. Does that mean the firebase functions only work if it's hosted on firebase?

Answer (score 1):

To provide a bit fuller of an answer:

The example you provided relies on a Firebase.json file. This file provides configuration if (and only if) your application is hosted with Firebase hosting ([see docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#the_firebasejson_file)).

If you expect to host your app elsewhere, you'll need to make sure your `/redirect` path points to the Firebase function URL itself (probably something like https://us-central1-project-name.cloudfunctions.net/redirect). In the authorization flow, the LinkedIn module in the example repo then will redirect to either a [default or a configured callback url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-linkedin#oauth-20).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. So from what I understand, through logic on popup.html, the first time the popup is opened, the redirect function is called (I replaced /redirect with the function URL). Once the redirect flow is finished, the function then redirects back to popup.html, which then calls the token function (I changed the callback to popup.html and changed /token to the token function). Once I get to the token function call, I'm running into "Error in the token Function: undefined". Do you see anything that I might've missed? The firebase function logs aren't very helpful.

Comment: Again, really appreciate your help. I think I've narrowed the issue down to a couple of lines of code. In popup.html (https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/linkedin-auth/public/popup.html) line 56 calls tokenReceived.name. The tokenReceived function takes in data, but we don't pass in data on the call. So, tokeReceived goes into the "else" (because there's no data) and prints "error in the token Function: " data.error. Data.error is undefined.